# Custom Colormap for mayavi for a contour3d of a 3D array of scalars

Tags: python, mayavi

I have a 3D array of scalars representing different physical elements of a mesh, i.e. solid, liquid, or a different material of solid. I'd like to set scalars equal to 1 to be [0,1,1], scalars equal to 2 to [0,1,0], and scalars equal to 3 equal to [1, .67, 1]. I'm not sure how to define a custom colormap based on a scalar field, i.e. each scalar value in the array being associated with a specific color.

```
import mayavi.mlab as ml
def visualize(self):
        if len(self.geo) == 0:
            self.create_geo()
        ml.contour3d(self.geo, transparent = True)
        ml.gcf().scene.parallel_projection = True
        ml.show()
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you have tried so far to solve the presented problem.

Comment: So far I've looked into the custom colormap documentation, which seems related, but the documentation doesn't seem to apply to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428645/mayavi-mapping-a-discrete-colorbar-on-a-surface

This solved it for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mayavi mapping a discrete colorbar on a surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428645/mayavi-mapping-a-discrete-colorbar-on-a-surface)